# Syntax error at end of input. How to fix it?

Tags: sql, function, pgadmin-4

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertuser
     (username VARCHAR,
      emails VARCHAR, 
      address VARCHAR, 
      creditcard INTEGER, 
      purchase VARCHAR,
      product_id VARCHAR,
      number_of_products INTEGER)
```

I keep getting the error

> ERROR:  syntax error at end of input
>   LINE 10: ^
>
> SQL state: 42601
>   Character: 181

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

I've tired to add parentheses and refreshed just in case my server timed out

Comment: Well your function appears to not have any body.  Is there one?

Comment: You only posted 8 lines, yet the error is on line 10. Please post your full SQL, or we really can't help you.

Comment: this code describe a table. Create table user (...)